# Fill a table from CSV file with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to import data from this SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempExchangeRates](
    [currency (Libellés)] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Currency Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [2019-03] [float] NULL,
    [2019-04] [float] NULL,
    [2019-05] [float] NULL,
    [2019-06] [float] NULL,
    [2019-07] [float] NULL,
    [2019-08] [float] NULL,
    [2019-09] [float] NULL,
    [2019-10] [float] NULL,
    [2019-11] [float] NULL,
    [2019-12] [float] NULL,
    [2020-01] [float] NULL,
    [2020-02] [float] NULL
)
```

With sample data:

[image]

To this one:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExchangeRates]
(
    [IdExchangeRate] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ExchangeRateCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [ExchangeRatePeriodStartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ExchangeRatePeriodEndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ExchangeRateValue] [decimal](20, 5) NULL,
    [CurrencyCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
)
```

Now I want to call a stored procedure to get fill the real table like that:

I start with stored procedure like that but I'm not sure how I could do that

```
------------------------- 3. Declare StartDateTable --------------------
        DECLARE @StartDateExchangeRate TABLE
        (
          rowid INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
          value float,
          startDate date
        )

    --  Insert Into @StartDateExchangeRate(value, startDate)
        --This finds the start dates by finding unmatched values
        --SELECT id,value
    --  from ExchangeRates

    ------------------------- 2. Declare EndDateTable --------------------
        DECLARE @EndDateExchangeRate TABLE
        (
           EndDate date
        )

        Insert Into @ENdDateExchangeRate(EndDate)
        --This finds the start dates by finding unmatched values
        SELECT EOMONTH(startdate)
        FROM @StartDateExchangeRate As ER1


        -------------------------3. Join NotYet--------------------------
```

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are trying to do or what part(s) you need help with.

Comment: Your question is far too broad. You will have a better experience on SO if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I need help to write the stored procedure so i can  import data from a temporory table to the final one (not the same shema)

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with? Creating a stored procedure?

Comment: yes plz create the procedure stored to insert the data from the first table to the second one, like shown in the code i don't have the same shema  ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is lacking in details

Assuming the `TempExchangeRates` columns will vary as time goes on, here is a option that will dynamically UNPIVOT the data so it can be inserted into your final structure.

**Example (or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7b9c2fe2af4d82d96856cf19965b4880))**

```
Select ExchangeRateCode            = A.[Currency Code]
      ,ExchangeRatePeriodStartDate = period
      ,ExchangeRatePeriodEndDate   = EOMonth(period)
      ,ExchangeRateValue           = B.Value
      ,CurrencyCode                = replace(upper(A.[currency (Libellés)]),' ','')
      ,CreatedBy                   = 'SomeString'
      ,CreatededAt                 = getdate()
 From  [TempExchangeRates] A
 Cross Apply ( Select period = try_convert(date,[Key]+'-01')
                     ,Value  = try_convert(float,value) 
               From OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
               Where [Key] not in ('currency (Libellés)','Currency Code')
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: thank u so mush for ur answer but for date start and date end the id is a must be a month i must 01/01/2019 to 31/01/2019 etc..

Comment: @nada The image has next month.   Small change... just use EOMonth(period)